# How to pass parameters while calling controller's function using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, controller

I am using below function to call a function on controller:

```
  function getPartialView(actionUrl, targetDiv, ajaxMessage, callback) {
        showAjaxMessage(targetDiv, ajaxMessage);

        $.get(actionUrl, null, function (result) {
            $(targetDiv).html(result);
            callback();
        });
    }
```

and calling it like this:

```
  getPartialView("UCDamage", "#dvdamageAreaMid", "Loading...", function () { });
```

this function provides me facility just like updatePanel in classic asp.net web forms.
now please tell me how can i pass values in function as a parameter.

actually the UCDamage is a user control which will be randered in div:dvdamageAreaMid.
the code is written on current form on which i am displaying this userControl named "UCDamage". but i need to pass some values to this function in controller.

my controller function is like this:

```
  public ActionResult UCDamage(string searchText)
    {           
        SecureModelService service = new SecureModelService();
        return View(service.ListBodyWork(searchText));
    }
```

i have tried with taking textbox with namex searchText and retrieve its value but not able to get it.

Please provide me some suggestion and help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass values to your controller via the second parameter in your $.get call. Something along the lines of

```
$.get(actionUrl, { searchText: "hello world" }, function (result) {
        $(targetDiv).html(result);
        callback();
    });
```

The jQuery documentation has some examples on how to do this:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/